# CRONTAB no ejecuta archivo php en servidor ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, webservice, ubuntu, cron

hola estoy intentando ejecutar un archivo php con una inserción a base de datos mysql. pero no consigo que el cron haga su función en el servidor ubuntu. Deseo saber que estoy haciendo mal y como solucionarlo para que se ejecute cada minuto en el servidor.

CODIGO DEL ARCHIVO PHP: reportar.php

```
<?php
require_once '../config/config.php';
include "database.php";
include "func.php";
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
$hora = date('h');
$min = date('i');
$seh = date('s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO cron (idcron,data) VALUES (NULL,'Hola esto se ejecuto en = $hora:$min - $seh')";
setData($sql);
echo $sql;
?>
```

CAPTURA DE LOS FICHEROS PARA VER LA RUTA DEL FICHERO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CAPTURA DEL CROMTAB.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CAPTURA DEL CRON HECHO EN UBUNTO COON PUTTY.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Trata de ejecutarlo ocupando wget, también no olvides proporcionar permisos de ejecución al archivo en cuestión

Comment: como seria la configuración entonces , me lo puedes escribir.

Answer (score 1):

El primer paso para crear una tarea programada en php a travez de cron 
es probar que realmente se esta ejecutando dicha operacion.
paso previo debes tener instalada la libreria phpx.-cli donde x es tu version de php. 
primero que nada crea un archivo php de test

```
<?php  
echo "Hola mundo";
?>
```

guardalo como test.php, ejecutalo a través de la linea de comandos a través de:

```
php test.php
```

si obtienes el resultado esperado entonces el ambiente esta configurado correctamente.

Para ejecutar la tarea programada debes hacerlo a través de curl, 
curl miscript.php o a travez de un bash de linux, debes crear un archivo que haga el llamado al script php.

```
#!/bin/sh
php /var/www/html/public_html/libs/reportar.php
```

Luego lo guardas como tarea_programada.sh,
le das los atributos de ejecución a dicho archivo con:

```
chmod +x tarea_programada.sh
```

Ultimo paso, creo que ya lo sabes es agregar dicho script a el crontab,
debes editar el archivo /etc/crontab y agregar la linea que hará el llamado al script:

```
*/1 * * * * usuario /var/www/html/public_html/libs/tarea_programada.sh
```

Espero que esto haya aclarado tus dudas, saludos.